# php replace for readline

Tags: php, readline

I want use this code in broswer.
first I have to intialize the 'myclass', after I have to intialize the 'com'

```
$class = new myclass(readline('one'));
$class->com = readline('two');
```

so I changed it to:

```
$class = new myclass($_GET['one']);
if(isset($_GET['two'])){
$class->com = $_GET['two'];
}
```

but in this way, when I pass 'two', it will intialize 'myclass' again,
or if I use statement for first line, the second line can't access to the first line

Comment: How do You "call" the code in browser?

Comment: site.any/index.php?one=value, after site.any/index.php?two=value2

Comment: You cannot call "two" *after* "one". You have to call it in single request (`$class` lives only until the single request ends): `site.any/index.php?one=value&two=value2`

Comment: I can't send both together

Comment: That's bad, because if You send them separately, the script is called two times, creating different `$class` every time. Why can't You send both values in single request?